# Оператор доступа точка к методу и к переменной

Tags: java

Задачка из книги Сьерра "Изучаем Java".
Поясните пожалуйста почему в коде вызываем и метод ta[x].setArea(), а потом еще и переменную этого метода ta[x].area? Почему нельзя было сразу обратиться к переменной при выводе не печать?

```
class Triangle {
double area;
int height;
int length;
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    Triangle [] ta = new Triangle[4];
    while (x < 4) {
        ta[x] = new Triangle();
        ta[x].height = (x + 1) * 2;
        ta[x].length = x + 4;
        ta[x].setArea();
        System.out.print ("треугольник " + x + ", зона");
        System.out.println (" = " + ta[x].area);
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
    public void setArea() {
        area = (height * length) / 2;
    }
```

}

Comment: Во первых, area это переменная класса, а не метода. Во вторых, как вы, наверное, заметили, в методе есть определённая логика: area = (height * length) / 2. Для этого, в том числе, используются методы вместо обращения напрямую к переменным (полям) класса.

Comment: Если что, "оператор точка" это называется разыменование (когда к полю класса) и вызов метода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке

```
ta[x].setArea();
```

устанавливается новое значение переменной `area` (для каждой точки треугольника свое), а в строке

```
System.out.println (" = " + ta[x].area);
```

мы получаем это значение (четыре раза разное).

Дело в том, что обращаться напрямую к полям класса (переменным) — плохо, так как не реализуется инкапсуляция, один из [принципов ООП](https://habr.com/ru/post/87205/).

Поэтому поля класса принято объявлять с [модификатором доступа](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.3.php) `private`, а доступ к ним (из других классов) получать не напрямую, а с помощью функций `set***`(сетеров) и `get*** (гетеров)`, где `вместо ***` название поля класса.

Почему-то в этой задаче используется сетер, но нет гетера. Используя принцип инкапсуляции, можно переписать этот код таким образом:

```
   public class Triangle {
    private double area;
    private int height;
    private int length;
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    Triangle [] ta = new Triangle[4];
    while (x < 4) {
    ta[x] = new Triangle();
    ta[x].height = (x + 1) * 2;
    ta[x].length = x + 4;

    ta[x].setArea();
    System.out.print ("треугольник " + x + ", зона");
    System.out.println (" = " + ta[x].getArea());
    x = x + 1;
}
}
  public void setArea() {
    area = (height * length) / 2;
}
  public double getArea (){
  return area;
  }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ !

Answer (score 0):

Принято разделять методы по функциям. Обычно на один метод - одна функция.
Пока один класс - все просто; а когда у тебя 100 классов в разных пакетах - такая практика применяется для улучшения читабельности кода